# Calling WCF with PHP -- variable structures

Tags: php, .net, wcf

I have a WCF Service written in .Net 4.0 that accepts two parameters.  One is a complex type consisting of User, MerchantName, and Password, the second variable is an int.  The service returns a third complex type.

It's structure looks like the following:

//******C# Code* *

```
public sub AccountData Log(Login LoginData, int AccountID)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Using SoapClient and removing the int AccountID from the C# service, I can pass the complex data in and parse through the complex data output succesfully.  Adding the AccountID parameter, breaks the soap call.  I can't seem to compound the variables into one array in a fashion that WCF will accept.

The question is how to form the array to pass in the call?

I have tried the following:

```
//****Attempt one *******

$login = array('MerchantName' => 'merchantA',
        'User' => 'userA',
        'password' => 'passwordA');

$account = '68115';  //(also tried $account = 68115; and $account = (int)68115;)
$params = array('LoginData' => $login, 'AccountID' => $account);
$send = (object)$params;  //Have tried sending as an object and not.

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$result = $client->__soapCall('Log', array($send);
var_dump($send);
echo("<pre>");
var_dump($result);
```

The latest attempt was to class the variables but I got stuck when tring to form into the $client call.

```
class LogVar
    {
        public $MerchantName;
        public $User;
        public $Password;
    }
    class AccountID
    {
        public $AccountID;
    }

    $classLogin = new LogVar();
    $classLogin->MerchantName = 'merchantA';
    $classLogin->User = 'userA';
    $classLogin->Password = 'passwordA';

    $classAccount = new AccountID();
    $classAccount->AccountID = '68115';
    //How to get to $client->__soapCall('Log', ???????);
```

P.S. I'm a .Net coder, please be kind with the PHP explanations...  Also NuSoap didn't seem much better, however it may have undiscovered ways of dealing with complex types.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with standard SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
$data = $client->Log(array('AccountID' => 23, 'LoginData' => array('User' => '123', 'Password' => '123', 'MerchantName' => '123')));
    // echo $client->__getLastRequest();
var_dump($data);
```

You can display the last request XML and compare it with what a WCF client is generating. This is how I figured it out: I generated a WCF client, inspected the XML message generated by it and compared to $client->__getLastRequest.

Note: You can call the method by its name on a SoapClient rather than use $client->__soapCall('operationName')